# Proving the congruency of triangles

Tags: geometry

How can I prove the congruency?

I have tried,
$\angle{CDA}=\angle{DCB}$
But, which rule should I use?

[image]

Comment: You also have $BAC$ and $ACD$. There is also $DAC$ and $ACB$ Do you know the Z rule?

Comment: You can do it by both the way given in answers. I think with parallelogram you can do it faster. Just keep watching, figure and you will get it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT : The quadrilateral $ABCD$ is a parallelogram.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Notice how there are parallel lines, and use alternate interior angles. Also notice how they share the side $AC$